Confused about the p-value and Cohen's d
I have the following code that computes both the p-value and cohen's distance.
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind


# Calculate Cohen's d
def calculate_cohens_d(group1, group2):
    mean_group1 = np.mean(group1)
    mean_group2 = np.mean(group2)
    std_group1 = np.std(group1, ddof=1)
    std_group2 = np.std(group2, ddof=1)
    n_group1 = len(group1)
    n_group2 = len(group2)
    pooled_std = np.sqrt(((n_group1 - 1) * (std_group1 ** 2) + (n_group2 - 1) * (std_group2 ** 2)) / (n_group1 + n_group2 - 2))
    cohen_d = (mean_group1 - mean_group2) / pooled_std
    return cohen_d

# Function to simulate data and perform t-tests and Cohen's d calculation
def perform_experiment():
    # Simulate data
    group1_EXP = np.random.normal(80, 10, 10)
    group2_EXP = np.random.normal(81, 10, 10)
    
    # Perform multiple t-tests
    _, p_value_EXP = ttest_ind(group1_EXP, group2_EXP)
    cohen_d_EXP = calculate_cohens_d(group1_EXP, group2_EXP)

    return p_value_EXP, cohen_d_EXP


if I run the code twice with a given seed:
# Seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(42)

# Perform 2 experiments
p_value_EXP, cohen_d_EXP = perform_experiment()
print(f'p-value: {p_value_EXP:.4f}, Cohen\'s d: {cohen_d_EXP:.4f}')

p_value_EXP, cohen_d_EXP = perform_experiment()
print(f'p-value: {p_value_EXP:.4f}, Cohen\'s d: {cohen_d_EXP:.4f}')

I get:
p-value: 0.0029, Cohen's d: 1.5402
p-value: 0.9792, Cohen's d: -0.0118

And so would say that the first experiment with a p-value of 0.0029 and a 'large' Cohen distance is significant.
I contrast, I would say that the second experiment is not that significant.
Now, if I run the simulations 1,000 times
# Perform 1000 experiments

n_simulations = 1000
 
p_values_EXP = np.zeros(n_simulations)
cohen_ds_EXP = np.zeros(n_simulations)

for i in range(n_simulations):
    p_values_EXP[i], cohen_ds_EXP[i] = perform_experiment()


# Calculate proportions of p-values > 0.05
prop_p_value_EXP_greater_0_05 = np.mean(p_values_EXP > 0.05)

print("Proportion of p-values > 0.05:", prop_p_value_EXP_greater_0_05)

I get
Proportion of p-values > 0.05: 0.951

which would mean that it more likely to observe a non-significant outcome. But the first 2 experiments show the opposite.
So I am not sure about the usefulness of Cohen's distance in that case.

What exactly do you mean by "in that case"?

when having n = 10 here.

The key point is that both the p value and Cohen's d are random variables, and we usually observe only a single realization.
Under the null hypothesis of equal underlying distributions, the p values will be uniformly distributed on the unit interval. (See "The Dance of the p values" on YouTube.) Cohen's d also has some distribution, which will depend on the sample size and the variance of the underlying distributions.
In your simulations, the null hypothesis does not hold, but your simulated distributions are very close to each other: they differ by just one tenth of a standard deviation. So the p values will be almost uniformly distributed (but with a somewhat higher chance than 5% of being below 0.05), and Cohen's d will have an expected value of -0.1.
While the sample size goes into the calculation of the p value, it does not enter the calculation of Cohen's d. Cohen's d just has a larger variance for smaller sample sizes, and to this extent, an estimate of d based on a small sample should be taken with a grain of salt. Which is of course also true for any other estimate based on a small sample size.
Below are simulated distributions of Cohen's d under your assumptions and calculations, for $n=10$, $n=100$ and $n=1000$. The means over 10,000 simulations are -0.10 in each case, as it should be, but the variances are much larger for small $n$.

R code for the simulations:
nn <- c(10,100,1000)
n_sims <- 10000

cohens_d <- matrix(NA,nrow=n_sims,ncol=length(nn))
for ( ii in 1:n_sims ) {
    set.seed(ii)    # for reproducibility
    for ( jj in seq_along(nn) ) {
        group_1 <- rnorm(nn[jj],80,10)
        group_2 <- rnorm(nn[jj],81,10)
        pooled_std <- sqrt(((nn[jj]-1)*var(group_1)+(nn[jj]-1)*var(group_2))/(2*nn[jj]-2))
        cohens_d[ii,jj] <- (mean(group_1)-mean(group_2))/pooled_std
    }
}

opar <- par(mfrow=c(1,length(nn)),las=1,mai=c(.3,.6,.5,.1))
    for ( jj in seq_along(nn) ) {
        hist(cohens_d[,jj],xlim=range(cohens_d),main=paste("n =",nn[jj]),xlab="")
    }
par(opar)


Thanks. I thought Cohen's d would be helpful to discuss the effect size. But apparently, it does not help much when the sample is small. In this case, the best would be to calculate the power then ?

If by power you mean "post hoc power", no, please don't do that, see Hoenig & Heisey (2001). If $n$ is small and the variance is large, then it's just a fact that your estimate of d is just one observation out of a very noisy distribution. Calculate it, report it, point to its unreliability, and try to get more data or control the variability more, e.g., by restricting the population.

Does Cohen's d really have a larger variance for smaller sample sizes? It just uses the observed variance, which could be large or small, regardless of the sample size. Is it not the CI of Cohen's d which will be much wider for smaller sample sizes? Should it be Cohen's d just has a wider CI?

@jginestet: yes, it normalizes by the observed standard deviation, but that is not enough. I edited my post to show simulations of Cohen's d for various values of $n$, take a look.

@StephanKolassa, indeed, the variance of the sampling distribution of $d$, which is directly related to the width of the CI of $d$ OK, I misread your statement.

As @Stephan Kolassa mentioned in his comment, post-hoc power is redundant with the p-value. The post-hoc power is deterministically related to the p-value; if you got a low p-value, it is because your power was "high enough" (in this one experiment), and if your p-value is high, it is because your power was low (in this one instance). And vice-versa (if the power was high, then you got a low p-value, etc...). See here, here or here.
But just as p-value and post-hoc power are deterministically related, so are are p-value and post-hoc effect size; if the p-value is low, this is because the effect was large (in this one instance), etc... See e.g. this post on CV.
So, are you learning anything new from the effect size that you did not know from the p-value? Not in terms of statistical significance. You may however learn something about the practical significance of the result (e.g. you may find that a given treatment lead to statistically significant weighth loss, but since the low bound of the CI of the effect is 0.5lb, it is probably not clinically significant).
So, to directly answer your question "I am not sure about the usefulness of Cohen's distance in that case", in your case, where you just have simulated data and no context, it has absolutely no usefulness; the p-value told the whole story. If you had real data, with a context where we could judge of the practical significance of your results, it would.
As to why you got 1 significant result out of 2 in your initial experiment? You just got "lucky".
